# Keras CNN does not work on M1 MacBooks - NSRangeException - NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript: Index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, apple-m1

I was trying to test out ResNet for my new M1 MacBook Pro - with Apple's new tensorflow version 2.4.0-rc0 and Numpy version 1.21.1 - with the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_image


model = keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(weights="imagenet")


china = load_sample_image("china.jpg") / 255
flower = load_sample_image("flower.jpg") / 255
images = np.array([china, flower])

images_resized = tf.image.resize(images, [224, 224])
inputs = keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input(images_resized * 255)


y_proba = model.predict(inputs)
```

Which gives the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018cea8c78 __exceptionPreprocess + 240
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018cbd10a8 objc_exception_throw + 60
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018cf73b68 -[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:].cold.1 + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018ce16ac8 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:] + 188
    4   MLCompute                           0x00000001962f06a0 -[MLCDeviceCPU(MLCLayerOperations) updateTensorsForFusedPaddingAndConvolutionLayer:layerNext:] + 276
    5   MLCompute                           0x00000001962f0e5c -[MLCDeviceCPU(MLCLayerOperations) fuseLayersForGraph:stopGradientTensorList:startAtLayerIndex:forInference:] + 1264
    6   MLCompute                           0x0000000196352f68 -[MLCInferenceGraph compileWithOptions:device:inputTensors:inputTensorsData:] + 1868
    7   _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so      0x0000000144e16848 _ZN10tensorflow9mlcompute7convert26MLCGraphConversionPassImpl15ConvertSubgraphEPNS_15OpKernelContextEPNS1_11TFGraphInfoEPKNS_5GraphERKNSt3__16vectorINSA_12basic_stringIcNSA_11char_traitsIcEENSA_9allocatorIcEEEENSF_ISH_EEEERKNSB_IiNSF_IiEEEEPNS1_24MLCSubgraphConvertResultE + 3516
    8   _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so      0x0000000144df8498 _ZN10tensorflow9mlcompute7kernels13MLCSubgraphOp20ProcessMLCSubgraphOpEPNS_15OpKernelContextEPPNS1_10MLCContextEPPNS1_15TFContextStatusE + 416
    9   _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so      0x0000000144dfb1c0 _ZN10tensorflow9mlcompute7kernels13MLCSubgraphOp7ComputeEPNS_15OpKernelContextE + 804
    10  libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib     0x00000001587a7598 _ZN10tensorflow12_GLOBAL__N_113ExecutorStateINS_21SimplePropagatorStateEE7ProcessENS2_10TaggedNodeEx + 2772
    11  libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib     0x000000015881a50c _ZN5Eigen15ThreadPoolTemplIN10tensorflow6thread16EigenEnvironmentEE10WorkerLoopEi + 552
    12  libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib     0x000000015881a1e4 _ZZN10tensorflow6thread16EigenEnvironment12CreateThreadENSt3__18functionIFvvEEEENKUlvE_clEv + 80
    13  libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib     0x000000015880bacc _ZN10tensorflow12_GLOBAL__N_17PThread8ThreadFnEPv + 104
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018cd2b878 _pthread_start + 320
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018cd265e0 thread_start + 8
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Please let me know whats up - it seems that none of the other questions with the same NSRangeException are concerning Keras. The same issue on GitHub was closed.

I am new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: tensorflow_apple is not really new anymore, since TensorFlow 2.5 you do not need it, see here: https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/

Comment: Yeah! Please use metal-plugin from Apple for installing  Tensorflow as Dr. Snoopy suggested in above comment. Newer version 2.9 even includes support for  distributed Training.